# "nvprof --query-metrics" gives CUDA profiling error

Tags: cuda

"nvprof --query-metrics" gives CUDA profiling error. Says could not find any metrics. How to overcome? My gpu is GTX 960.
Operating System Cent OS 6.5.
Cuda 6.5, 64 bit version
 Here is the output given by my machine.

[root@Sekhar finalCodes]# nvprof --query-metrics

Available Metrics:
                            Name   Description
Device 0 (GeForce GTX 960):
======== Error: CUDA profiling error.

[root@Sekhar finalCodes]# nvprof --analysis-metrics

======== Warning: Metric "stall_imc" cannot be found on device 0.

======== Warning: Metric "stall_compute" cannot be found on device 0.

======== Warning: Metric "stall_texture" cannot be found on device 0.

======== Warning: Metric "stall_other" cannot be found on device 0.

======== Warning: Metric "stall_exec_dependency" cannot be found on device 0.

======== Warning: Metric "stall_inst_fetch" cannot be found on device 0.

======== Warning: Metric "stall_sync" cannot be found on device 0.

and many more lines like this.

All my programs are compiled and executed fine.

Also nvprof ./myFile gives the following output.

==4075== Profiling application: ./myFile

==4075== Profiling result:

Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name

99.94%  71.093ms       500  142.19us  135.17us  146.46us  void collideKernel(SodA, int, int, int)

0.05%  37.151us         9  4.1270us  3.9990us  4.5120us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]

0.01%  7.7760us         2  3.8880us  3.8720us  3.9040us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

==4075== API calls:

Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name

75.44%  285.43ms        18  15.857ms  4.3210us  285.35ms  cudaMallocPitch

19.14%  72.422ms      1000  72.421us  1.1560us  218.21us 
cudaEventSynchronize

3.30%  12.491ms      1000  12.490us     706ns  11.523ms  cudaEventCreate

0.87%  3.3010ms       500  6.6010us  5.9150us  37.636us  cudaLaunch

0.49%  1.8493ms      1000  1.8490us  1.4670us  22.908us  cudaEventRecord

0.17%  660.35us       500  1.3200us  1.1920us  4.1100us  cudaEventElapsedTime

0.15%  579.85us        83  6.9860us     445ns  264.17us  cuDeviceGetAttribute

0.15%  575.57us         1  575.57us  575.57us  575.57us  cudaGetDeviceProperties

0.11%  422.92us      2000     211ns     169ns  2.9590us  cudaSetupArgument

0.06%  220.54us        11  20.048us  12.854us  62.371us  cudaMemcpy2D

0.04%  158.03us        18  8.7790us  3.3490us  81.821us  cudaFree

0.04%  155.07us       500     310ns     274ns  1.9820us  cudaConfigureCall

Comment: What metric(s) are you trying to query?

Comment: I have a gtx 960 with CUDA 7.5 on linux,  and I have no trouble running `nvprof --query-metrics` on it.  If you want help, you're probably going to have to provide more information.  My suggestion would be to provide answers to each of the following (you can edit your question): 1. What OS are you using?  2. What CUDA version are you using?  3. Can you run CUDA codes properly on your GTX960, such as `deviceQuery` and `vectorAdd` sample codes? 4. Provide the exact `nvprof` command and output from that command (copy and paste your session into the question).

Comment: try updating your CUDA version from 6.5 to 7.5.  Make sure you have a proper driver installed for CUDA 7.5 i.e. 352.xx or newer.

Comment: I got the metrics with NVIDIA driver 352.63 and Cuda 7.5 in CentOS 6.5. I have another GPU GTX 650Ti, with Cuda 5.5 where even the option --metrics is not recognized. Thanks for the information. A lot to study/interpret with the metrics...Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

With NVIDIA Driver 352.63 and Cuda 7.5.18, the metrics are available except a very few metrics like

```
 "l1_shared_utilization" 
 "alu_fu_utilization" 
 "l2_l1_read_transactions" 
 "l2_l1_write_transactions" 
 "nc_l2_read_transactions" 
 "l2_l1_read_throughput" 
 "l2_l1_write_throughput" 
 "nc_l2_read_throughput" 
 "atomic_throughput".
```

Newer driver and toolkit versions gives events and metrics.

Comment: There is no such thing as CUDA 7.8.